# Will the Legacy address on Ledger hardware wallets always be supported?

Tags: security, bitcoin, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallets

Ledger hardware wallets apparently have 2 different HD path types: **Legacy** and **Ledger Live**. Will the Legacy wallet addresses still be accessible and operational in new device models like the Ledger Stax coming out next year? Or is there a possibility that the Legacy wallet could be closed/inaccessible at some point in time and I could lose funds linked to the Legacy wallet?

A lead Ledger dev gave the following answer in a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/a3zb7f/my_eth_account_says_legacy_should_i_bother_making/), but it's from 4 years ago. Does his answer still stand in 2023?

[image]

Since the seed phrase of any Ledger device is shared between the Bitcoin and Ethereum wallets in the device, it would also be good to know: Is the **Bitcoin legacy** wallet also supported perpetually in future Ledger devices, as opposed to **Bitcoin segwit** wallets?